# Is there a letter at this position on the list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, position, letter

I'm trying to write a function that determines if a letter is present at a certain row and column on a list of lists.

```
#Input:

lst2 = [['.', 'W', 'W', 'E', 'E'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'f'],
        ['A', 'A', 'A', '.', 'f']]

#Output: is_space_occupied(0, 1, lst2) should return True because 'W' is present on that spot 
        while is_space_occupied(1, 1, lst2) should return False because '.' is present on 
        that spot and not a letter.
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def letter_on_spot(row,col,lst):
A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for row in lst:
    for col in lst:
        if col == A:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Edit: I'm getting return outside function as an error for return True and am not sure if my function works correctly

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: My code doesn't work correctly and is getting errors I was hoping someone could see what could be wrong with it. I was told this could be done with 2 for loops and an if-else statement but cant figure it out

Comment: Post your errors in your question.

Comment: Given the value of `A`, what do you think `col == A` is doing?

Comment: I think I should change that to return True I'm bascially trying to say if the column is a letter then that letter is present on the list

Comment: You don't need for loops or anything for this, just an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues here.

First, you're looping unnecessarily; you provide the indices for the list so you only need to check if the value with those indices is contained inside the string `A`. No need to traverse through every element just to check one; index the list `lst`.

Second, `col == A` will always fail (unless `col = 'ABCD..yz'`). You compare their values when you should be checking if `A` contains `col` with the `in` operator.

In short, you could change your function to:

```
def letter_on_spot(row,col,lst):
    A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return lst[row][col] in A
```

and get the wanted result -- `True`/`False` based on the contents of a given index.

Ideally, some error checking should be performed in order to now allow indices that result in `IndexError`s; play around with the lists' `len` for that, something like this:

```
def letter_on_spot(row,col,lst):
    A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    if row >= len(lst) or col >= len(lst[row]): 
        return False    
    return lst[row][col] in A
```

where, before trying to access `lst`, you check if the bounds are acceptable by testing against the length of the list `lst` and the length of the sub-list `lst[row]`.

Comment: Thank you Jim this works perfectly but how could I have this function return False if the letter is not at the position or if it is a non-letter character

Comment: I'd really suggest using `str.isalpha()`. The intent is arguably clearer, and there's no chance of forgetting one or more characters.

Comment: @warrior4223 If a letter is not in the position specified by `lst[row][col]` you'll get `False` returned due to the `in` check failing. If it is a non-letter character? You mean punctuation?

Comment: @rainer I'd agree with that but I didn't want to deviate from the code he had *too* much.

Comment: So if the input was 'is_space_occupied(5, 5, lst2)' would this function return False since that position doesn't exist on the list of lists or how could I have it do this? I'm not sure what it's currently doing in that situation

Comment: @warrior4223 Right, you'd need to check against that as I specified in my last sentence. I edited my answer now to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indices to access list elements:

```
x = [10, 11, 12, 13]
x[1] # => 11
```

The same works for lists of lists:

```
lst2 = [['.', 'W', 'W', 'E', 'E'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'f'],
        ]
lst2[2]    # => ['A', 'A', 'A', '.', 'f']
lst2[2][1] # => 'A'
```

Now, all you need to do is check whether the symbol there is a character. Python provides `str.isalpha()` for that:

```
lst2[0][1].isalpha() # => True
lst2[1][1].isalpha() # => False
```

Note that `str.isalpha()` would also return `True` for strings with more than one character (eg. `"hello".isalpha()` returns `True`).If that is of concern, just check the string's length which you can get using `len()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is wrong with you code but a shorter alternative is the following:

```
def letter_on_spot(row,col,lst):
    return lst2[row][col].isalpha()
```

Comment: No need for the extra parentheses or calling the method on the `str` class. `return lst2[row][col].isalpha()` will do.

Comment: Thanks! I modified it!

Answer (score 0):

letter_on_spot(row, col, lst) takes two integers (hopefully) and a list as input

lets go over this step by step:

```
for row in lst:
```

same as saying for each smaller list in lst

```
for col in lst:
```

same as saying for each smaller list in lst
so that's your first issue; we want to go through the elements of row, not lst

```
if col == A:
```

assuming we fixed the above problem, are we checking if col is the same as A, or are we checking if col is **in** A?

we can access the elements of lst and check if its a letter with the following:

```
if lst[row][col] in A:
    return True
else:
    return False
```